# How many original Xbox systems could you system link together?

Tags: xbox

I was discussing this with a co-worker and we are trying to remember if it was 4 or 8 original Xbox game consoles that you could link together to play games.

I think it was 4. He thinks it was 8. So what say you oh wise fellow gaming nerds?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on [the Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Xbox_System_Link_games) listing all System Link compatible games, it looks like the maximum number of consoles that could be linked varies from game to game. The maximum number of consoles able to be linked appears to be Delta Force: Black Hawk Down, at 32 consoles.

Comment: I found [a page](http://eliteownage.com/xboxlan.html) that says "you can connect 16 or even more Xboxes," but I would agree with the answer above that 16 is the max.  It also seems to be dependent on the game as well.  The same page says for *Halo Combat Evolved,* if you want to play a 16 player match, you can't use 16 Xboxes through system link.  Instead, it would be 4 Xboxes with 4 people on each.

Comment: The numbers given for Delta Force: Black Hawk Down suggest that 32 consoles can be linked.

Comment: @Random832 oh you're right, I missed that, I'll update this. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Given the last comment, now I wonder if there really is a limit. I said previously it's also game dependent, but I'm wondering if there is an actual limitation.

Comment: @TimmyJim, hardware-wise, I'd think no, but you'd have to program it for a game and I don't think any game supports more than 32.